# how do i update pytermgui window with live data?

Tags: python, user-interface, tui

I have set up a gui with pytermgui (just my windows so i can put in widgets)

```
    manager.add(
        ptg.Window("solar") # , etc.
```

but want to change the content of the window periodically (with some live data eventually)

whats the refresh function/loop function for pytermgui windows?

Thanks